# cannot recover stout after silencing it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, stdout

I am trying to suppress the print statements in a function imported from a library. I use Python 3.6 in Jupyter Notebook.

I used:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
x = myfunction()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Unfortunately this succeeds in suppressing the print statements, but not in reinstating them afterwards. So I cannot print anything after this unless I restart the kernel.

How could I fix this?

Comment: I tried this and the print works after third line (sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__) .

Comment: @serbia99 strange... are you also on jupyter notebook?

Comment: @AlexisEggermont jupyter notebook uses IPython under the hood, which overwrites `sys.stdout`. You will need to keep a copy of the old stdout and restore using that rather than using `sys.__stdout__`.